# iframe from same origin doesn't load with Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp

Tags: iframe, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

I have web page with an iframe inside it:

```
<?php
header('Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="assets/html/menu.htm"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine in firefox.

If I add

```
header('Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp');
```

Firefox doesn't show the iframe content. Error:

```
Blocked Page

An error occurred during a connection to <domain>.
```

I need both headers to enable `crossOriginIsolated`.

The iframe and the main page have the same origin, why firefox doesn't show iframe content after adding second header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `object` tag instead of `iframe` tag solved the problem:

```
<?php
header('Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin');
header('Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <object data="assets/html/menu.htm"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This only happens on Firefox, both Chrome and Edge load the iframe correctly.
Do you think it's a problem with the header settings or the Firefox implementation is incorrect?